# How to find the internet data usage of all users and categorized per user in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, internet, users

Want to get the data usage of all users in Ubuntu like:

- username1 = datausage
- username2 = datausage
- username3 = datausage

etc

Answer (score 0):

Try vnstat. Here is a link to the Ubuntu page.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMonitorInternetTrafficTotals